# I have an ArrayList<JCheckBox> that i want to convert to an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcheckbox

I have an `ArrayList<JCheckBox>` that i want to convert to an `ArrayList<String>`

First I do like this. I get all my titles from a file and put them into a new ArrayList. Afterwords I make a new JCheckBox Array that contains all the Strings from the StringArray.

```
ArrayList<String> titler = new ArrayList<String>();
titler.addAll(FileToArray.getName());

ArrayList<JCheckBox> filmListe = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
for(String titel:titler){
    filmListe.add(new JCheckBox(titel));
}
for(JCheckBox checkbox:filmListe){
    CenterCenter.add(checkbox);
}
```

This is what I am trying to do: First I make a new ArrayList (still in the JCheckBox format), that contains alle the selected Checkboxes. Afterwords I want to add the to a new ArrayList in a String format.

The main problem is italicized (with **):

```
ArrayList<JCheckBox> selectedBoxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();

for(JCheckBox checkbox: filmListe){
    if (checkbox.isSelected()){
        selectedBoxes.add(checkbox);
    }

ArrayList<String> titlesArr = new ArrayList<String>();
for(JCheckBox titel:selectedBoxes){ 
    *titlesArr.add(titel);*
}
```

A lot of code and text for a little problem! But I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the checkbox's label is exactly the same as what you originally had in your list of titles, just use the checkbox's `getText` method (which gets the String label). You don't need to make a separate list of checkboxes that are checked - just put an if-block inside your first loop like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> titlesArr = new ArrayList<String>(filmListe.size());

    for (JCheckBox checkbox : filmListe) {
        if (checkbox.isSelected()) {
            titlesArr.add(checkbox.getText());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been starring at this program for too long. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't add a `JCheckBox` to a `List<String>`, the types `JCheckBox` and `String` are incompatibles.

I guess you want to add the text of the check box into your list, so you have to retrieve it manually, using:

```
titlesArr.add(titel.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> titlesArr = new ArrayList<String>();
for(JCheckBox checkbox: filmListe)
    if (checkbox.isSelected())
        titlesArr.add(checkbox.getText());
```

Now `titlesArr` contains what you wanted.

Comment: Using `toString` on an object in this way is a very bad idea, as you depend on its implementation, which is only usually supposed to be used for debugging. In your case, calling `toString` on a `JCheckBox` would result in a horrible output like "javax.swing.JCheckBox[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0......"

Comment: Fixed. Mind telling constructive comments like that, *before* downvoting?